# using loops in stored procedures in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure with 5 parameters.

```
@1,@2,@3,@4,@5
```

Five Columns

```
@a,@b,@c,@d,@e
```

One of them is of string types(@a) which contains "N" number of numeric values separated by coma(,).

ex:

```
@a= '1,2,3,4,5,6'
@b='a'
@c='f'
@d='g'
@e='h'
```

My requirement is to insert "N" number of rows .

The value of rest four parameter's will remain same for every row whereas the value of `@a` parameter will be fetched by splitting `@a`.

The table will look like the attached file

[image: table structure]

Comment: Cursor.  But why 1-6 why not just 6?

Comment: thanx xQbert..@a Contains 6 values for column a. So i need 1-6..

Comment: What was the question here?

Comment: `My requirement is to insert "N" number of rows.` (I'm guessing OP is looking for methods to accomplish this)

Comment: Hi Dean...i gotta insert these values like u see in the table..how to insert it..m badly stuck here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table testtable(a int, b char, c char, d char, e char)
go

declare @a varchar(20)= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'
declare @b varchar(20)='a'
declare @c varchar(20)='f'
declare @d varchar(20)='g'
declare @e varchar(20)='h' 

INSERT testtable(a,b,c,d,e)
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)'), @b, @c, @d, @e
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(@a, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)

select * from testtable
```

Comment: @user1172910 that should not make any difference. There will be an implicit conversion

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure InsertABC, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to int.

Comment: you must have invalid data in @a. If you want, i can produce a full working example with a testtable

Comment: @a='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'

Comment: @user1172910 I included a fully working example, maybe it is one of your other columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52309/discussion-between-user1172910-and-t-clausen-dk)